# How to remove the blue arrow(?) in the fish shell

Tags: fish

I was using zsh and oh-my-zsh at first, but people said fish shell was better, so I switched to fish shell. But there is a problem, if you look at the picture below, there is a blue arrow on the left, is it removable?, if it's, how could I remove it? It's only appear in the iterm2. There is no blue arrow in the mac primary terminal app.

[image: screenshot of the iterm2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's iTerm's shell integration mark that tells you where the prompt is.

To disable it, go to Prefs>Profiles>Terminal>Show mark indicators and turn that off.